# HA Proxy ACL on domain name and context name

Tags: haproxy

I have request coming from different URLs like

```
https://example1.com/context1
https://example1.com/context2
https://example2.com/context1
https://example2.com/context2
```

There might be multiple domains with multiple context names. Want to do configurations in HA proxy and redirect to particulate `backend`. Can I have `acl` on domain name and context name in single line or can we do nested `acl` in HAProxy `frontend`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets do it like this:

```
acl context_url url_reg -i -f /etc/haproxy/context_urls.list
use_backend context_backend if context_url

backend context_backend
  # your config here
```

And in the file /etc/haproxy/context_urls.list

```
# regex for context urls
/context\d
```

Comment: Thanks. I have almost 10 context and around 85 different domains. It means I have almost 850 combinations to be handle. Using above configuration, do I need to repeat `acl` for each domain and context name? I can define multiple `backend`. But want to do `acl` with minimum configurations.

Comment: You can add many regexps to the list files. And you already have backends. Or what are you trying to do?

Comment: But then how single `acl` that is `context_url`points to multiple `backend`?

Comment: You'll have to use an acl for every backend. And you already have backends. Or, you can use a single  acl for several backends if they are similar. And you can write rules with combinations of hdr(host) and url_reg conditions in acls. And you can from logical expressions from several acls.

Comment: Without actually seing your configurations I would not we able to invent the best way to do it.

Comment: Ok. Then what's the use to have separate file with list of context names. Also I have multiple domains. so for each domain and context, I have to write separate acl. Can I do domain and context check in single acl, backend resolution and keep that configurations in different file? Do you have any example having single acl in separate file and points to multiple backens?

Comment: I'm using separate files because I have many lines there and it's easier to manage. Yes you can use logical expressions wth several acls and several conditions.

Comment: Splitting haproxy config to several files in a conf.d way is not possible but there is a patch to support it.

Comment: I still don't undertand the logic you are trying to do. For example for the 4 lines you provided which and where should be sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41553/discussion-between-navnath-and-dilyin).

Comment: Not able to message you from chat. Basically I have list of domains and context and each one need to refer different backends. I will configure backends. But there any way to minimise acl configuration which is I am looking for

Comment: Is there any common logic? Or is the assignment arbitrary?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you want to ask.

Comment: Could you try the chat again...

Comment: No. I just try but it's not working. I Will try to explain. I have more then 80 domains and around 10 different contexts. Now for each domain, each context configured on different systems. So I need to have different backends for combination of domain and context. How Can I configure this in separate file and include in haproxy.cfg?

Comment: Most likely you will need to have a backend for every place where you vant to send the request. Probably it's just a backend for every server and you should already have them.

Comment: Next, you need a set or rules to sort the requests. I don't know what logic is being used in your case to determine what should be sent where. In the worst case id there is no logic and decisions are random you will require an acl for every domain and context combination. But I guess that there is a set of logical rules you are using and they can be formalized so the job can be done with much fewer acls.

Comment: How exactly would be better to sort your requests I cannot tell without knowing the logic. For example, you can create an acl for every of 80 domain and for every of 10 contexts. Then you can send requests to servers using conditions like this: `use_backend server4 if domain2 and context5` But perhaps you can group servers and contexts, and you can use lists in external files for this: `use_backend server5 if domain_group3 and context_group8 and !context_group3` Or, you can do it without exteran files manually specifying the list of server and context for the ack grouop in the haproxy config.

Comment: Try reading this: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.7.html#7

Comment: This really helps me. One last question. Can we configure list of backends in separate file and include those files in `haproxy.cfg`?

Comment: Not with default haproxy, but there is a patch to do it